# Trouble setting console window title in C++

Tags: c++, windows, console

I've been trying to learn how to make C++ apps with the Windows API. I tried using a simple function, `SetConsoleTitle()`, to set the title of the console window. This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    TCHAR abc[5];
    abc[0] = 'H';
    abc[1] = 'E';
    abc[2] = 'L';
    abc[3] = 'L';
    abc[4] = 'O';
    SetConsoleTitle(abc);
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    system("pause > nul");
}
```

This was the result

[image]

The title was just supposed to be `"HELLO"`. What are the other characters doing there, and how do I get rid of them?

I used Visual studio Code 2019 to compile this code.

Comment: you need to null terminate your string

Comment: On a side note, you really shouldn't be using `TCHAR` in this example. It has no place in modern code, and besides if you ever set your project to Unicode then this code will not compile correctly as-is because you are not using the `TEXT()` macro for the character literals, eg: `abc[0] = TEXT('H'); ...` You should get rid of `#include <tchar.h>`, change `TCHAR` to `char`, and change `SetConsoleTitle` to `SetConsoleTitleA`. Or better, use `wchar_t` and `SetConsoleTitleW` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau for ASCII characters there's no need for the `TEXT` macro, because a `char` will upcast to `wchar_t` just fine.  It's only characters beyond U+007f or actual strings that need the macro.  And even that's obsolete, because you can probably just prepend `L` to everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @AlanBirtles says, you need to null terminate your string.  That's the only way C++ knows how long the string is.  There are three ways to do that:

```
TCHAR abc[6]; // <-- increase this size
...
abc[5] = '\0'; // <-- add this
```

```
TCHAR abc[] = "HELLO";  // the terminator will be added automatically
```

```
TCHAR abc[6] = {0};  // the string will consist of all nulls and you can then overwrite just the first 5
```